# How can I create Google Charts in server side whitout a headless browser?

Tags: c#, phantomjs, gchart

I need to export some pdf's sometimes whitout showing the chart data on the page.
We are using phantomjs to have a headless browser, and then get the images from phantom to PDF, but this approach is sometimes slow.
We are looking to create a faster solution, whitout the need of a headless browser.

Our backend is built in C#.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: so basically you want to access PDF's at server side ?

Comment: Actually @Prany., what I want is to generate a PDF at the server side, using some charts from gcharts.

Comment: Probably should edit the title to reflect than you're looking for solution *other* than headless browser.